# Java GET request no protocol?

Tags: java

I have made a GET request to my localhost (just testing something) and I keep getting this error!

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: localhost/register.php?username=chris&password=chris&email=chris@gmail.com
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.mcmonitor.sys.HttpUtility.sendGetRequest(HttpUtility.java:34)
at com.mcmonitor.sys.Main.sendGet(Main.java:28)
at com.mcmonitor.screens.LoginScreen$3.actionPerformed(LoginScreen.java:94)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What is it? Here is the method sending the GET request:

```
public static HttpURLConnection sendGetRequest(String requestURL)
    throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setDoInput(true); // true if we want to read server's response
    httpConn.setDoOutput(false); // false indicates this is a GET request
    return httpConn;
}
```

Copied from the internet since i've been trying for a good 20 minutes now. Can anyone shed some light on this? Much appreciated

btw here's the request:
localhost/register.php?username=chris&password=chris&email=chris@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

> java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: localhost/register.php?

This tells you you need a protocol (like HTTP or HTTPS). Change your request to `http://localhost/register.php?...`.  Java isn't like Chrome where it will infer you meant http/s. You have to provide a full URL.

Comment: Not dumb. It happens.